# Is f continuous at $ x = \pm 2 $ and everywhere else it isn't continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2 - 2, & x \in \mathbb{I}, \\
-x^2 +2, & x \in \mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}
 $$
Is $f$ continuous at $ x = \pm \sqrt{2} $ and everywhere else it isn't continuous? I think it's easy to prove where it isn't continuous because of the density of the set of reals but how do I prove the continuity in $ x = \pm \sqrt{2}$? I tried it by definition but got stuck.

Comment: Simply plugging $x=\pm 2$ into both equations give different results. Why would it be continuous?

Comment: Perhaps the OP meant $x = \pm\sqrt 2$, which seems like a more reasonable question?

Comment: Yes sorry I corrected it

Comment: Perhaps I'm old-fashioned, but $\Bbb I$ is not in my repertoire. I suggest $x\notin\Bbb Q$ instead.

Comment: Do you understand *intuitively* why this function is continuous at $\pm\sqrt{2}$, and is it just the definition that is tripping you up?

Comment: Yes I do, Mees de Vries. I just don't know how to prove it.

Comment: I can't find the right $ \delta$

Comment: More generally, if $g,h\colon \Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ are continuous then 
$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}g(x)&x\in \Bbb Q\\h(x)&x\notin\Bbb Q\end{cases}$$
is continious precisely at those $x$ where $g(x)=h(x)$.
Sometimes such a generalization makes finding the right argument easier ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $f(\sqrt{2}) = 0$, and that
$$ x^2-2 = (x-\sqrt{2})(x+\sqrt{2}), $$
so that
$$ |-x^2+2 - 0| = |x^2-2 - 0| = |x-\sqrt{2}||x+\sqrt{2}|.  $$
Note that when $x$ is close to $\sqrt{2}$, the right factor is close to $\sqrt{2}$, and the left factor is small.

Can you find your delta using this?

Answer (score 1):

You can show this with the $ \epsilon, \delta  $ definition by showing that there you can find a $ \delta_1 $ small enough s.t. if $ x\in(\pm2-\delta,\pm2+\delta) $ then for rational x $ |f(x)-f(\pm2)|<\epsilon $ and you can find such a $ \delta_2 $ for irrational x and just calling $ \delta=min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\} $.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = 0$ for $x = \pm\sqrt{2}$. Hence we have to show that $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to\pm\sqrt{2}$. This is equivalent to $\lvert f(x) - 0 \rvert = \lvert x^2 -2 \rvert \to 0$ which is obviuos.